Stabilizer of subset being a subgroup under certain conditions
Problem: Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$ and let $Y\subset X$. I have shown that the stabilizer of $Y$ $$G_Y=\{g\in G\mid gy\in Y \text{ for all } y\in Y\}$$ is a submonoid of $G$. I know this is not necessarily a subgroup, but on the other hand I can't think of an example showing this. I also want to show that $G_Y$ is indeed a subgroup, if either $Y$ is finite or $G_Y$ is finite.
So far: For the last part it suffices to show that $G_Y$ contains inverses, since we already know it's a submonoid. Supposing $Y$ is finite, say $Y=\{y_1,\ldots, y_n\}$, taking any $g\in G_Y$ means that $gy_i=y_j$ for some $i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then $$g^{-1}y_j=g^{-1}(gy_i)=(g^{-1}g)y_i=ey_i=y_i\in Y,$$ so $G_Y$ is a subgroup. Now supposing $G_Y$ is finite, I came to some sort of conclusion but I really didn't use the finiteness assumption, so I know I must be going wrong somewhere.

There are different stabilisers of a set (pointwise, setwise), see here. In the latter post, $g.Y=Y$ is required, whereas you have only $g.Y\subseteq Y$. But if you have $g.Y=Y$, then this stabiliser is a subgroup.

Yes, but I'm specifically asking about the one I mentioned.

So then you have your answer. $G_Y$ is a subgroup if $G_Y=G_{{Y}}$.

This fact I already know, but the result should hold assuming $G_Y$ is finite. And $G_y$ for a single element $y$, i.e. the stabilizer of $y$, is not necessarily finite, so we're leaving out some cases.

Your proof in the case that $Y$ is finite is incomplete. Also, you don't (clearly) use that $Y$ is finite. (You just introduce some indices.)

Referring to this submonoid as the stabilizer of $Y$ is non-standard and is to be deplored!

@DerekHolt Edit the post then :)

A finite submonoid of a group is necessarily a subgroup (consider the powers of an element etc.). In particular, $G_Y$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $G_Y$ is finite.
If $Y$ is finite, then $gY \subseteq Y$ already implies $gY = Y$ since both sides are finite sets of the same cardinality. And clearly, $gY = Y$ is equivalent to $Y = g^{-1} Y$. This shows that, when $Y$ is finite, $G_Y$ is a subgroup as well.
To get a counterexample, consider $G = \mathbb{Z}$, the free group of rank $1$. Then the action is just an automorphism $\alpha : X \to X$, and for $Y \subseteq X$ we have $G_Y = \{z \in \mathbb{Z} : \alpha^z(Y) \subseteq Y\}$. If $\alpha(Y) \subseteq Y$, we do not necessarily have $\alpha^{-1}(Y) \subseteq Y$. Consider $X = \mathbb{Z}$, $\alpha(z)=z+1$ and $Y = \mathbb{N}$. Then $G_Y = \mathbb{N}$, and this is not a subgroup of $G$.
